# How do I create a pie chart in google sheets without a category or two from my data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a list of data, showing 4 items.  Cats, dogs, giraffes, eggplant.

I want to create a pie chart in google sheets that shows the pie with just cats, dogs, and giraffes.  I don't want to show the chart with eggplant.

Is there a way to print out the chart without one or two categories from the list of data?

So instead of it showing this:
[image: e]

I would like it to show this chart, but without me needing to sort, deleted, manipulate the data.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a new filter view and filtering out `eggplant`

- Go to menu > `Filter views`
- `Create new filter view`
- Deselect `eggplant`
- `OK`

[image]

After creating the filter view, within the chart setting you are given the choice to `Include hidden/filtered data`

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?